# Linq to sql query between two tables

Tags: c#, string, linq-to-sql

I have two tables

**Table : "Role"**

```
Role_Id   Role_Name        Role Description
1         Administrator    Can mange everything
2         Ticket_Manager   Can manage tickets
3         Ticket_User      Can solve a ticket
```

**Table : "User"**

```
User_ ID    User_Name     User_Role(Foreign Key to Role table)
1           Harry         2
```

My question is how can i get Role_Name if I know the User_Name (For exemple Role of "Harry")? I need a code for linq to sql.

Result should be in string
for exmpl :

```
string s = (query);
```

string[] result = {s};
return result;

I am trying to find a solution for 2 hours but not getting any positive result

Comment: what have you tried?  have you Googled joining tables in sql or linq because these searches would give you what you need most likely...

Comment: I did but didn't find anything with "where" condition.
All the given results and exemples are with "var" but i need with "string" instead of var. hope you understand my problem

Comment: With the code you marked as an answer below `var` will preform the same as `string` because it is typed by the `.Single<string>();` portion of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string result = (from r in (your db context).Role
            join u in (your db context).User on r.Role_ID equals u.User_Role
            where u.UserName.Equals("Harry")
            select r.Role_Name).Single<string>();
```

Did you mean like that?

Comment: Hi jan thank you for your support. I have already tried this bt actualy i need it in a string instead of "var". for exemple string s = from r in .....

then i make a table of string : string[] results = {s};  return s;

Answer (score 0):

```
var username = "Harry";

var result = db.Users
    .Where(x => x.User_Name == username)
    .Select(x => x.Role.Role_Name)
    .Single()
```

You should notice the following

1. result is actually of type `string`. This is called [Implicitly Typed Local Variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx)
2. `Single()` assumes that there is one and only one result. You may or may not need one of the following methods: `Single()`, `First()`, `SingleOrDefault()`, `FirstOrDefault()`. A great article on the diferences is [LINQ Single vs SingleOrDefault vs First vs FirstOrDefault](http://www.technicaloverload.com/linq-single-vs-singleordefault-vs-first-vs-firstordefault/)

Comment: Hi Carlos thank you for your support. I have already tried this bt actualy i need it in a string instead of "var". for exemple string s = from r in .....

then i make a table of string : string[] results = {s};  return s;

Comment: @HarjinderRandhawa I decided to explain my answer a little better